# Onclick current date and time in datetime-local input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am trying to get the current date and time on a `datetime-local` **input** **field**, using an `onclick` method.

I have tried using `moment.js` and other **libraries** to do this, but for some reason, it cannot translate into the current `datetime-local` field. What am I doing wrong?

I decided to go back to basics with `jquery` alone and this is what I manged to get so far.

If you change the input type to `text` on the input box, the script works fine, but if its changed to datetime-local, it doesn't work.

```
    $(
    function(){

        $('#time').click(function(){
                  var time = new Date();                
                  $('#time-holder').val(time.toDateString());  
        });

    }
);
```

JsFiddle: [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicholas116/zq680sua/7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When use  **input type** `datetime-local`.

The date format must be as: `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'`

e.g: **`"2014-11-16T15:25:33"`**

```
$(
    function(){
     
        $('#time').click(function(){
            var time = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
            $('#time-holder').val(time);  
        });
        
    }
);
```

solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/alvarojoao/4hehnepw/

Comment: I'm glad it helps @d1sciple

Comment: Should be 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'